# Data Preprocessing handling null values using fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-preprocessing

Recently while pre processing a raw csv file to replace the missing values I have used the mean of the values in that col, the code snippet is (assume df is the DataFrame and time is one of the column or attribute where the values are in float format representing hours)

```
df.time = df.time.fillna(df.time.mean())
```

after that the null value were successfully replaced with mean now **I want to print only the rows which have been affected by the command instead of displaying the entire DataFrame** how can I do that?

Comment: perhaps you can create a new column and then use the older column to find the affected rows

Answer (score 0):

You can't get these rows after you have performed the operation as this information is lost.

But you can get the indices of all the rows that have null values first, and then print all of those rows afterwards:

```py
na_rows = df.time.isnull()
df.time = df.time.fillna(df.time.mean())
print(df[na_rows])
```